# how write queries in the RealmList?

Tags: java, android, realm

i have models:

```
public class Feed extends RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
private int id;
private boolean active;
private Section section;
private RealmList<Job> jobs;
// getters and setters
......
}



public class Section extends RealmObject {

private String title;
private String subtitle;
private String url;
private String imageSrc;
// getters and setters
......
}


public class Job extends RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
private long id;
private boolean fultime;
private boolean contract;
private boolean remotely;
private String company;
private String link;
private String job;
private Date pubDate;
private String logoUrl;
private String bonus;
private String location;

// getters and setters
......
}
```

I want get feeds with jobs only remotely.
Get feeds with jobs only remotely, this is easy, but I want to the list of vacancies each tape were only job working remotely

There are several rss feeds vacancies grouped by type, such as design, backend. I parse and caches them with the Realm. Work can be remote , contract, fultaym. I want to get the feed with her vacancies, example only with vacancies fultaym work.
for example, there are feeds
|design  |count job 40|
|backend |count job 60|
.....
i want to add filters, for example only fultaym
|design |count job 35|
|backend|count job 51|
........

sorry for my english

Comment: Sorry, it is a bit unclear what you mean. Do you want to get a list of available remote jobs grouped by their pubDate?

Comment: There are several rss feeds vacancies grouped by type, such as design, backend. I parse and caches them with the Realm. Work can be remote , contract, fultaym. I want to get the feed with her vacancies, example only with vacancies fultaym work.
for example, there are feeds
|design  |count job 40|
------------------------------------------
|backend|count job 60|
.....
i want to add filters, for example only fultaym
|design |count job 35|
------------------------------------------
|backend|count job 51|

Comment: Do you only want the number of jobs or do you want to list the actual jobs?

Comment: i want get feeds with list actual jobs.

Comment: sorry, it's really done with a Realm?

Answer (score 1):

Christian from Realm here. One thing to remember about Realm is that it is not a relational database, so sometimes you have to consider a different object model to be able to express the queries you want.

In your case you would need to add the Feed to the Jobs as well, and then query the Jobs directly like so:

```
public class Job extends RealmObject {
  ...
  Feed feed;
}

RealmResults<Job> results = realm.where(Job.class).equalTo("fulltime", true).findAllSorted("feed.id")

// Getting the count for each feed type would then require something like this:
RealmResults<Feed> feeds = realm.allObjects(Feed.class);
for (Feed feed : feeds) {
  int feedCount = results.where().equalTo("feed.id", feed.getId()).count();
}
```

Comment: You have very good documentation, thank you for it. I do not like questions that are reduced to decide for me, so he took the example of documentation unfortunately chose the example of poorly reflecting the essence of the problem(and i accidentally copied the wrong example  class User). Update question.